# Ruby: Reopening a Class from within a Module

Tags: ruby, class, syntax, structure

Why doesn't this work?

```
module XT
  puts Fixnum.class  # So we're sure to re-open the Fixnum class
  class Fixnum
    def hi
      puts "HI from module XT"
    end
  end
end
```

After requiring and loading the module, the `hi` method is still not added to Fixnum. It works if I remove the module wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining `XT::Fixnum`, not `Fixnum`.

Answer (score 6):

As @Jeremy wrote, constants are namespaced by modules, and defining a class is really just assigning a class object to a constant. Basically,

```
class Fixnum; end
```

is (roughly) equivalent to

```
Fixnum = Class.new
```

(except for the fact that if `Fixnum` already exists, the former will reopen it, while the latter will overwrite it).

This means that if you do that inside of a module (or class, since class IS-A module), the constant `Fixnum` will be namespaced inside that module.

If you want to explicitly access a top-level constant, you can tell Ruby to start its lookup at the top-level in a very similar vein to how you tell Unix to start filesystem lookup at the top-level:

```
module XT
  class ::Fixnum; end
end
```